# Storing mouse coordinate values in python (pygame)

Tags: python, variables, click, mouse

My issue is that in python I am building a program that is similair to paint, in the sense that the user has the ability to click, and move his/her mouse around (which changes size of rectangle accordingly) and then click again to set the dimensions of the rectangle

here is my code:

```
            import pygame 

            pygame.init() 

            #colours
            white = (255,255,255) 
            black = (0,0,0) 
            blue = (0,0,255)
            red = (255,0,0)
            green = (0,255,0)
            #################### 

            #window settings
            gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))  
            pygame.display.set_caption('INTERFACE')
            ##########################

            #pre-defined variables
            gameExit = False 
            colour = black 
            x = 0 
            y = 0
            count = 0 

            ######################################### 

            #frames per second initialzing 
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            ###############################3

            while not gameExit:  
                for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                        gameExit = True   

                #retrieves coordinates of the mouse
                m_x,m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()    

                #Background colour
                gameDisplay.fill(white)  

                print count   

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and count == 0: #If count is zero and user clicks mouse then make count equal to one
                    count = 1 

                if count == 1: #if count is equal to one make a black retangle that has size properties following the mouse coordinates
                    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [x,y,m_x,m_y]) 


                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:  #if the user releases the mouse button make count equal to 2
                    count = 2  

                while count == 2: #while count equals to 2 make another red rectangle with same properties as the black one then if user clicks again make count = 0
                 pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [x,y,m_x,m_y]) 
                 if count == 2 and pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
                        count = 0
                pygame.display.update() 
                #frames per second actual value
                clock.tick(15)

            pygame.quit() 
            quit()
```

So what I have so far is that I am able to get the user to click and use the mouse to change size of the rectangle the part where the user clicks again to set the rectangle in place is confusing me I am not sure in how to actually store the ever changing mouse coordinates, because whenever I assign variables they change along with the mouse movements, how I want to store the latest coordinates that were last associated with the making of the rectangle.

Comment: So what I have so far is that I am able to get the user to click and use the mouse to change size of the rectangle the part where the user clicks again to set the rectangle in place is confusing me I am not sure in how to actually store the ever changing mouse coordinates, because whenever I assign variables they change along with the mouse movements, how I want to store the latest coordinates that were last associated with the making of the rectangle

Comment: When you assign a list to a variable, it points to the same list, so when the list is changed, the variable changes. What you want to do is assign like this: `new_list = old_list[:]` or `new_list = list(old_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a list to a variable, it points to the same list, so when the list is changed, the variable changes. What you want to do is assign like this:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

or

```
new_list = list(old_list)
```

Ex:

Before:

```
>>> ol = []
>>> nl = ol
>>> ol.append(90)
>>> ol
[90]
>>> nl
[90]
>>>
```

Now:

```
>>> old_list = []
>>> new_list = old_list[:]
>>> old_list.append(90)
>>> old_list
[90]
>>> new_list
[]
```